# Date Dimension SSAS umm al qura Calendar

Tags: ssas

How to handle Umm Al-Qura date Dimension in SQL Server analysis, shall I handle it as date Dimension? Umm Al-Qura calendar is some kind of Hijri calendars used in Saudi Arabia.